# Not able to return variable from inside a function

Tags: android, function, kotlin, variables

So i'm trying to return a value from a function to use inside the mainActivity class, but I get an error when I try to return the variable stating that the 'variable must be initialized' even though I have given a value to it. Any thoughts on this?

```
private fun getCLocation() : LocationClass {

        var loc: LocationClass

        if(checkPermission()){

            if(isLocationEnabled()){

                locationVariable.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task->

                    val location:Location? = task.result

                    if(location == null){
                        Toast.makeText(this,"NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    else{
                        loc = LocationClass(location.latitude.toString(),location.longitude.toString())
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // location not enabled,open settings
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        } else {
            //Permission Not Enabled
            requestPermission()
        }

        return loc
    }
```

Error is: Variable 'loc' must be initialized

Comment: @RoarS. what should i assign over here as a 'default value' because loc is a variable of the type of a data class, it isn't string or int

Comment: @RoarS. I am getting null while trying to toast this variable in the onCreate function. But inside the else body where I have set the loc value, I can toast the value without any error

Comment: Getting the location is an asynchronous operation obtained in your listener callback.  The function as listed would never be able to return anything but null.

Comment: @Gardener Do you have any suggestions as to how should I return the location co-ordinates back to the OnCreate method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API or launches a coroutine return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two problems with your code:

1. The user may not have granted the permission yet, so it would enter the `else` block, where the function requests a permission, but doesn't do anything to set the initial location value. The function couldn't possibly return a valid location in this circumstance.
2. Getting location updates is asynchronous. Even if the permission is already granted, your OnCompleteListener will not be called until some time in the future, after this function has already returned. [You can read more explanations of what asynchronous APIs are here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o)

Here's a basic strategy for what to do. The function that gets a location takes a callback parameter instead of returning the LocationClass directly since it is asynchronous. You need a higher-level logic that can be retried after location or permissions become available.

```
private var triedPromptingLocationSetting = false
private var locationWorkflowInitiated = false // SET THIS BACK TO FALSE IN onViewDestroyed() IF IN FRAGMENT

private fun fetchCLocation(onReceived: (LocationClass?)->Unit) {
    if (!checkPermission() || isLocationEnabled()) {
        Log.e("Do not call getCLocation() before permission is granted and location is turned on! Ignoring.")
        return
    }
    locationVariable.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task->
        val location:Location? = task.result
        if (location == null) {
            onReceived(null)
        }
        else {
            var loc = LocationClass(location.latitude.toString(),location.longitude.toString())
            onReceived(loc)
        }
    }
}

// This is where the logic is for whatever you wanted to do with this location.
// In this example, it's assumed it would be called in onResume()
private fun doMyLocationWorkflow() {
    if (!checkPermission()) {
        requestPermission()
        return
    }
    if (!isLocationEnabled()) {
        if (triedPromptingLocationSetting) {
            // can't infinitely loop back to settings. 
            showSomeUiRequestingUserToManuallyEnableLocation()
        } else {
            triedPromptingLocationSetting = true
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        return
    }

    locationWorkflowInitiated = true

    fetchCLocation { location ->
        if (location == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            //...
            return@fetchCLocation 
        }
        // Do something with the LocationClass
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (!locationWorkflowInitiated) {
        doMyLocationWorkflow()
    }
}

private val locationPermissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) { permissions ->
        when {
            permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                doMyLocationWorkflow() // go back to original workflow
            }
            permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                doMyLocationWorkflow() // go back to original workflow
            } else -> {
                showSomeUiTellingUserPermissionMustBeGranted()
            }
        }
    }

private fun requestPermission() {
    locationPermissionRequest.launch(arrayOf(
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
}
```